# How to avoid subquery duplication? Getting multiple rows of subquery

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, subquery

I need to create a view like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bayer_pss_dashboard AS
SELECT
    m.machine_id AS machine,
    t.name AS time_interval,
    (
        SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, me.dt_start, IF(me.dt_end != '0001-01-01 00:00:00', me.dt_end, NOW()))) AS `unplanned_downtime`
        FROM machine_events me
        INNER JOIN event_types et on me.event_type_id = et.id
        INNER JOIN workspace_event_contains_machine_events wecme on me.id = wecme.machine_event_id
        INNER JOIN workspace_events we on wecme.workspace_event_id = we.id
        WHERE me.machine_id = m.machine_id
          AND me.dt_start >= datetime_from_interval(t.name)
          AND et.name != 'CONNECTION_ERROR'
          AND we.is_manual_event = 0
    ) AS unplanned_downtime,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total_number_of_stops`
        FROM machine_events me
        INNER JOIN event_types et on me.event_type_id = et.id
        INNER JOIN workspace_event_contains_machine_events wecme on me.id = wecme.machine_event_id
        INNER JOIN workspace_events we on wecme.workspace_event_id = we.id
        WHERE me.machine_id = m.machine_id
          AND me.dt_start >= datetime_from_interval(t.name)
          AND et.name != 'CONNECTION_ERROR'
          AND we.is_manual_event = 0
    )
    AS total_number_of_stops,
    (
        SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, me.dt_start, IF(me.dt_end != '0001-01-01 00:00:00', me.dt_end, NOW()))) AS `connection_errors_duration`
        FROM machine_events me
        INNER JOIN event_types et on me.event_type_id = et.id
        WHERE me.machine_id = m.machine_id
          AND me.dt_start >= datetime_from_interval(t.name)
          AND et.name = 'CONNECTION_ERROR'
    ) AS connection_errors_duration,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total_number_of_connection_errors`
        FROM machine_events me
        INNER JOIN event_types et on me.event_type_id = et.id
        WHERE me.machine_id = m.machine_id
          AND me.dt_start >= datetime_from_interval(t.name)
          AND et.name = 'CONNECTION_ERROR'
    )
    AS total_number_of_connection_errors
FROM machines m, time_intervals t;
```

This works fine, but I have performance issues due to the subquery duplication.
What is the best way to fix this? Is it possible to select multiple rows of a subquery?

I'm using MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: Eg. the last two can be made into a single CTE returning the sum and the count.  Seems like that goes for the first two too.

Comment: So I need two common table expressions. But have can I have multiple CTEs in one view?

Comment: Yes, of course, but perhaps it's possible to simplify your query even more.  Would you mind creating a db fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Please post full table definitions, including all indexes and constraints.

Comment: @bbaird you don't prefer a db fiddle?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Fiddle would be fine as well

Comment: Move the common subquery to a `JOIN`.

Comment: *I'm using MariaDB 10.3.* It supports CTEs - convert your subquery to it.

Comment: @DarkMath has left the building.